# How to get SOAP fault's faultcode when handling custom fault exception

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, soapfault, jbossws

Our system consumes SOAP Web Service, using JAX-WS client stubs generated based on service's WSDL. In case of error server returns SOAP faults like this:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header />
  <s:Body>
    <s:Fault>
      <faultcode>SomeErrorCode</faultcode>
      <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">Some error message</faultstring>
      <detail>
        <ApiFault xmlns="http://somenamespace.com/v1.0" xmlns:a="http://somenamespace.com/v1.0" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
          <a:RequestId>123456789</a:RequestId>
          <a:CanRetry>true</a:CanRetry>
        </ApiFault>
      </detail>
    </s:Fault>
  </s:Body>
```

Based on WSDL `SomeCustomFault` exception class is generated and all service methods are declared to throw this (see below) exception.

```
@WebFault(name = "ApiFault", targetNamespace = "http://services.altasoft.ge/orders/v1.0")
public class SomeCustomFault
    extends Exception
{
    private ApiFault faultInfo;

    public SomeCustomFault(String message, ApiFault faultInfo) {
        super(message);
        this.faultInfo = faultInfo;
    }

    public SomeCustomFault(String message, ApiFault faultInfo, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
        this.faultInfo = faultInfo;
    }

    public ApiFault getFaultInfo() {
        return faultInfo;
    }
}
```

As you can see this custom fault exception extends `Exception` and not [SOAPFaultException](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/xml/rpc/soap/SOAPFaultException.html). Hovewer I need to get SOAP fault's faultcode which could be retrieved only from [SOAPFaultException](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/xml/rpc/soap/SOAPFaultException.html) using [getFaultCode](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/xml/rpc/soap/SOAPFaultException.html#getFaultCode%28%29) method. Could you tell me how can I reach [SOAPFaultException](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/xml/rpc/soap/SOAPFaultException.html) or SOAP fault's faultcode in place where I catch above mentioned custom fault exception?

Comment: don't you have access to the returned SOAPMessage as such?

Comment: No. I have only thrown exception which is caught in my code

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could implement a JAX-WS [handler](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/ws/handler/Handler.html) and add it to your client web service reference.  This will be given opportunity to handle the request message and response message OR notified of a fault.

Create a `SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>` and your `handleFault()` method will be passed the `SOAPMessageContext`.  From that you can `getMessage().getSOAPBody().getFault()` to get the `SOAPFault`, which contains `getFaultCode()` and `getDetail()`.

Assign your new fault handler to your web service ref. One way is via `@HandlerChain`. It will be invoked prior to your `catch` clause.